# Select a list item on click in partial view

Tags: jquery, .net, model-view-controller

I have a list that contains a number of items contained in a partial view:

```
<ul class="ls-list">
    @if (Model.ItemList != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.ItemList)
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        @item.ID - @item.Name
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <li>NO CURRENT ITEMS</li>
        }
</ul>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>


@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("li").click(function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

I'm trying to pick up the value of a list item when the user clicks on that anchor but I cannot get my jquery function to fire. I need to get the value of the list item selected but only after the user clicks on the submit button.

I have no control over the design of the partial and am precluded from using a drop down list.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: So you are hiding li's after making a click over it?

Comment: No, that's just something I put in there to test if the function was firing at all

Comment: Can you tell exactly what do you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I did. I need to get a value from the list item that has been clicked. I'm setting the value of a property in the model with the value selected

Comment: you can use `$("a", this).text()` inside of that click event. Isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. When I click on the link text the event is not firing that I can see.

Comment: Bind event like this `$(document).click("click", "li", function () {... });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105270/discussion-between-crunchy-and-rajaprabhu-aravindasamy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a fit of idiocy I added the section in the partial view so of course my events were not firing. Simple solution is to either remove the section tag and leave the script:

```
<ul class="ls-list">
    @if (Model.ItemList != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.ItemList)
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="#" id="selectItem">
                        @item.ID - @item.Name
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <li>NO CURRENT ITEMS</li>
        }
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("a.selectItem").click(function (e) {
            $("#ID").val = e.ID;
            alert(this.text);
        });
      });
</script>
```

or add the section to the parent view. Personally I added it to the parent.